# Is there any way to compare two images of same person using Azure Cognitive Face API in JAVA

Tags: java, azure-cognitive-services

Is there any way to compare two images of same person using Azure Cognitive Face API in JAVA?
Which will give answer as Person is identical or not. And how much percentage they are identical.
I found one solution but its in C#.-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/howtoidentifyfacesinimage
Is there any thing available in JAVA?

Comment: [Why is “Is there any way to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: Did you try a web search? Why is **Azure Cognitive Services Face documentation** not enough to answer your question? --- [**Quickstart:** Detect faces in an image using the REST API and Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/java)

Answer (score 0):

You just had to look lower in the documentation, there is the link to the Java SDK:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/cognitiveservices/client/faceapi?view=azure-java-stable

And there is even a sample for your exact use-case, in Java

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/java

Generally, all cognitive services are exposed as REST API, so you can build it in the language you prefer...